# Why at any search keyword all time appears pagination?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I created pagination for my search page.
Controller -

```
public function action_index()
        {
            if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
                $pagination= Pagination::factory(array(
                    'total_items' => Model::factory('index')->get_count(),
                    'items_per_page' => 2,
                ));
                $this->template->content = View::factory('index/query')
                        ->set('query', Model::factory('index')->get_articles_from_query($_GET['search'], $pagination->offset, $pagination->items_per_page))
                        ->set('pagination', $pagination->render());
            }
            else{
                $this->template->content = View::factory('index/error')->set('message', 'Nav rakstu ar šādu atslēgvārdu.');
            }



    }
```

View -

```
    <?php

        foreach ($query as $item):

            echo '<h2><a href="/article/' . $item['slug'] . '">' . $item['virsraksts'] . '</a></h2>';
            echo '<p>' . nl2br($item['saturs']) . '</p>';

        endforeach;

        endif;
        echo $pagination;


?>
```

Model -

```
 public function get_articles_from_query($squery, $offset, $limit){

        $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM ieraksti WHERE virsraksts like :squery OR slug like :squery OR saturs like :squery ORDER By id DESC LIMIT :offset, :limit ')
                ->parameters(array(':squery' => "%$squery%", ':offset' => $offset, ':limit' => $limit))->execute()->as_array();
        return $query;
    }
```

The pagination appears all time. I want to pagination, when articles found over 2. Where is the mistake? What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Kohana 3.x, then set `auto_hide` to `true`.

```
$pagination= Pagination::factory(array(
                 'total_items' => Model::factory('index')->get_count(),
                 'items_per_page' => 2,
                 'auto_hide' => true
             ));
```

**Edit**

Kohana 2.3.x also supports `auto_hide`. See the [docs for Pagination](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/pagination).

**Edit 2**
If the above does not work for you, do not assign the pagination to the view, if you have less `total_items` then `items_per_page`.

```
        if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
            $items_per_page = 2;
            $total_items = Model::factory('index')->get_count();

            $pagination= Pagination::factory(array(
                'total_items' => $total_items,
                'items_per_page' => $items_per_page,
            ));
            $this->template->content = View::factory('index/query')
                ->set('query', Model::factory('index')->get_articles_from_query($_GET['search'], $pagination->offset, $pagination->items_per_page));

            if($items_per_page < $total_items) {
                $this->template->content->set('pagination', $pagination->render());
            }
            else {
                $this->template->content->set('pagination', '');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then do your own check. If `total_items` > `items_per_page` then assign your pagination to your view. Else don't.